# Code displays "::" on the terminal, cause unknown

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

```
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    int i;
    A(int i_ = 13) : i(i_)
    {
        cout << _FUNCTION_ << "\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << _FUNCTION_ << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* p = new A;
    A a();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, the code displays on my terminal "A::A". I get that the first A is called from first *FUNCTION* for "A* p" , but why does "::" appear? And the last A after "::" is from " A a(); "?

Comment: If you can't make heads or tails about where some output comes from, always delimit it. Instead of just declaring `p` and `a` right next to each other, print something (say `======`) after declaring `p` but before declaring `a`.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor for a type has the same name as the type itself.  `::` is the *scope resolution operator* and is used to name things contained within a named scope, such as a namespace or a type.

The constructor of `A` is therefore `A::A`.  The first `A` is the name of the type, and the second is the name of the constructor; the `::` is to indicate that the constructor is declared within the scope of the type.

This mirrors the way you would define type members following a declaration with no definition.  For example:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    A(int i_ = 13);
    ~A();
};

// Note how we have to refer to the constructor to define it since we are
// no longer within the scope of A:
A::A(int i_) : i(i_)
{
    cout << _FUNCTION_ << "\n";
}

// Similar for the destructor.
A::~A()
{
    cout << _FUNCTION_ << "\n";
}
```

You should only see `A::A` in your output.  Note that *you only create one `A` value here:*

```
A* p = new A;
```

You never `delete p;` and so you don't see the matching destructor call (`A::~A`) in the output.

This line does *not* create a variable of type `A`; rather, it declares a function called `a` that takes no arguments and returns an `A` value.  This function is never invoked (nor defined):

```
A a();
```

This is a vexing parse (not to be confused with the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)).  Clearly you intended to declare a variable, but this could be *either* a function *or* variable declaration, and the grammar prefers a function declaration.

To fix this, either remove the parens or use C++11's uniform initialization syntax:

```
A a;     // Default initialization
A a{};   // Uniform initialization
```

Comment: @Cybelle No problem. See my edit though; note that `A a();` does _not_ create an `A` variable. It declares a function!

Answer (score 0):

`_FUNCTION_` is a magic constant, therefore it posts the first "A" (name of the function called. Can't help with the rest though.